Continuous Beam-Beam Collider Luminosity Calculation
I'm trying to do a calculation of a continuous beam-beam collider luminosity where the crossing occurs in a defined volume and the beams are defined by their current densities. But I am getting stuck on trying to adapt the equations I find to the continuous beam scenario.
If I extend my understanding from this cern resource, I would think that since there is no density dependence on time or on the $z$ dimension, then the equation should be as shown below
$$\mathcal{L} = \frac{2vl}{e^2} J_1(x,y,z)J_2(x,y,z)$$
With $l$ being the length of the interaction region, $v$ the particles' velocity (assume $v_1 = v_2$), $e$ the fundamental charge, and $J$ the $2D$ current density, with units of $A/m^2$.
This equation though would have units of $[m^{-2}s^{-3}]$ which would be wrong for luminosity. Am I thinking about this the wrong way? Any input would be very much appreciated!
